# Can you embed the full YouTube player? Preferably via an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I've got [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pofekaindcmmojfnfgbpklepkjfilcep), and it uses jQuery to open a new Window with a YouTube video embedded in it. I do this with

```
$('#movie_player').get(0).getVideoEmbedCode();
```

This works great, but you don't get all of the video controls, like quality selection, CC, etc. Is there a way to embed the full player? I would prefer to do it via an API, like the `getVideoEmbedCode()` call that I'm currently using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it with the API, but I found a jQuery solution that worked. I just selected the containing element's HTML and sent it as a message via Chrome's API, then injected it into my new window.

```
$('#watch-video').html();
```